# Singularities of $f(z)=\frac{z\sinh 2}{(z^2-1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

What's kind of singularity at $z_0=1$ and $z_0=-1$ of f(z), with f(z):

$$f(z)=\frac{z\sinh z}{(z^2-1)^2}$$

I know they're both singularities of type "pole" (because the limit of f(z) as z goes to the singularities is $\infty$. However, I'm unable to find the pole's order.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: They're both second order poles.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. Mind telling me why?

Comment: Simply use the definition of pole order and find $k\in$ N such that $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^kf(z)=c$ with c non zero (which is unique)

Comment: Do you really mean to have $\sinh 2$ in the numerator or is that a typo?

Comment: @mrf, Why would that be a typo? It's not.

Comment: It just seems a bit weird to include a random constant in the function.

Comment: @mrf, you're actually correct! I'm such an... It's $\sin h z$.. I edited the main post.

Answer (score 1):

They're both second order poles, note that:

$$\frac{z\sinh(z)}{(z^2-1)^2}=\frac{z\sinh(z)}{4(z-1)^2}+\frac{z\sinh(z)}{4(z+1)^2}+\frac{z\sinh(z)}{4(z+1)}-\frac{z\sinh(z)}{4(z-1)}$$

Comment: Why the last 2 factors, if their sum is 0? Or is there a typo?

Comment: @user991 Typo, just fixed it.